# customerAccountManagementV1 SOAP Module WSDL broken since upgrading from v2.3.4 to v2.3.5

Tags: soap, wsdl, magento2.3.5

As mentioned in the title, the WSDL returned for the customerAccountManagementV1 module now contains an error in the response since upgrading from version 2.3.4 to version 2.3.5. Error shown below:

```
    <env:Fault>
        <env:Code>
            <env:Value>env:Receiver</env:Value>
        </env:Code>
        <env:Reason>
            <env:Text xml:lang="en">The &quot;\DateTime&quot; parameter type is invalid. Verify the parameter and try again.</env:Text>
        </env:Reason>
```

I'm new to Magento, and I am not in control of the web host. Any ideas what could be causing this please?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you in some or other way.

try to access all the SOAP methods using the below URL:
`http://www.domain.com/soap/all?wsdl_list=1`

you will get a file called all.xml or and confirm the message in the file. If the message is the same(

> `The &quot;\DateTime&quot; parameter type is invalid.`

) then probably the issue with the module named(`Dotdigitalgroup_Email`).

You can disable all three modules associated with it and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` commands again.

`Dotdigitalgroup_Email`, `Dotdigitalgroup_Chat` and `Dotdigitalgroup_Enterprise`

Change the value of `uioutss92djw2c14affydtjb2a8xngwj` what you will get using cURL response.

```
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer uioutss92djw2c14affydtjb2a8xngwj'
    )
);
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/soap/all?wsdl&services=customerAccountManagementV1';


$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($url, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'stream_context' => $context]);
var_dump($soapClient->__getFunctions());
```

Get the token using REST API, it will work Change the admin username and password as per system.

```
curl -X POST "http://www.domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{"username":"admin", "password":"password@123"}'
```